# Which of the objects of the class A would be created first in this code snippet?

Tags: c++

Which of the objects would be created first?

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    int marks;
};

int main()
{
    A ob1,ob2,ob3;
}
```

Would they be created at the same time or in the sequence as they are written?

Comment: obj1 will be created  first.

Answer (score 3):

Objects are created in the order in which they are declared. The comma operator doesn't change that.

Doing

```cpp
A ob1,ob2,ob3;
```

Is the same as doing

```cpp
A ob1;
A ob2;
A ob3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do

```
#include <ctime>
class A
{
    public: A()
    {
            std::cout << clock() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt you will be able to measure time difference in this case. And it is quite bad habit to deduce rules from behavior especially in C++

Comment: Yes your'e right, I should use clock() instead of time(0).

Comment: I think you missed both of Slava's points. 1. The construction is over in nanoseconds. What `clock` is going to be measuring is the `cout`. 2. C++ is the king of Undefined Behaviour. You cannot assume, without knowing the language rules, if compiler X gives a particular behaviour because it's a rule or because compiler X just does it that way. To this I'll add there is nothing in the given code that will tell you which object was constructed at the time reported by clock.

Comment: If you stored the result of `clock` as a variable and then queried which instance had the lowest time, maybe you'd get a useful measurement. Much easier would be to have a zero-initialized static counter and increment and store the counter in the constructor. The first object to be instantiated would have the lowest count, etc...